# program crashes when i try find MAC address

Tags: mfc, udp, client-server, ip-address, mac-address

i have a client server application in MFC using UDP  where the server displays the IP address of connected clients in a listbox. If i run the client and server on the same computer the program displays the MAC address **but if i try to run the client on a different computer the program crashes**. Here are the 3 functions. I have an event handler for the listbox that displays the MAC address in a second listbox when an IP address is selected. PrintMACFromIP is the code for getting the MAC address

```
void CmfcServerDlg::OnLbnSelchangeListClientaddr()
{
    BYTE Address[MAX_ADAPTER_ADDRESS_LENGTH];
    int nIndex = m_ClientAddrList.GetCurSel();
    if(nIndex < 0)
        return;

    CString s1;
    m_ClientAddrList.GetText(nIndex, s1);
    PrintMACFromIP(s1);

}

void CmfcServerDlg::PrintMACaddress(unsigned char MACData[])
{
    CString strText;
    strText.Format("%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X-%02X\n",MACData[0], MACData[1], MACData[2], MACData[3], MACData[4], MACData[5]);
    m_ClientIdList.AddString(strText); 
}


void CmfcServerDlg:: PrintMACFromIP(const CString &selected_ip_adr)
{
    IP_ADAPTER_INFO AdapterInfo[16];            
    DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof(AdapterInfo);       

    DWORD dwStatus = GetAdaptersInfo(           
        AdapterInfo,                            
        &dwBufLen);                         
    assert(dwStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);      

    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo = AdapterInfo;
    bool found = false;
    do {
        const IP_ADDR_STRING *addr_str = &pAdapterInfo->IpAddressList;
        while(addr_str != NULL)
        {

          if(selected_ip_adr == addr_str->IpAddress.String) 
          { 
            found = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if(found)
        {
          PrintMACaddress(pAdapterInfo->Address);
          break;
        }
        else
        {
            pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;      
        }
    }
    while(pAdapterInfo);                        
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting debug statements or tracing it down through an IDE? It more than likely is due to the use of a null pointer but you haven't provided enough information such as dumped core or stacktraces. You should also check if `pAdapterInfo` is NULL before using it.

Comment: i debugged it and found it gets stuck in the while loop. so is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: Where in the while loop?

Comment: it jumps out of the while loop when it reaches if(selected_ip_adr == addr_str->IpAddress.String) so found is never set to true

Comment: That's normal, if (selected_ip_adr == addr_str->IpAddress.String) if false then you will loop forever because addr_str never changes.

Comment: yes but what do i need to change in the code to be able to find the MAC address of another computer? this line is causing the problem

Comment: You are probably just missing a "addr_str = addr_str->Next" at the end of the inner while loop.

Comment: @LisaCollins: How are you advancing to the next pAdapterInfo.. think about that. There is a bug in your inner while loop.

Comment: @Michael Walz: ok so i put that line just after the if statement and when the program reaches that line it jumps out of the while loop and goes to the else statement. so whats the problem here? why can't it find the MAC address?

Comment: @0A0D: how do i fix this bug?

Comment: Keep in mind you shouldn't ask other people to debug your code, you should debug it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your bug is here :

```
while(addr_str != NULL)
{
   if(selected_ip_adr == addr_str->IpAddress.String) 
   { 
      found = true;
      break;
   }
}
```

Change the `while` to `if (addr_str != NULL)`

then

it should look like

```
if (add_str != NULL)
{
   if (selected_ip_adr == addr_str->IpAddress.String)
   {
      PrintMACaddress(pAdapterInfo->Address);
   }              
}   

pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;
```

This should handle if pAdapterInfo is null by using the do/while on the subsequent `next` calls.

See [IP_ADAPTER_INFO structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366062%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN.

Comment: ok so i ran that code but it hits the break. why isn't it finding the MAC address?

Comment: thanks for the code but the problem is still the same. it reaches the if statement and jumps out and executes the else. why won't it execute the if statement?

Comment: @LisaCollins: Which if? How many times does the while loop run?

Comment: if (selected_ip_adr == addr_str->IpAddress.String). you said remove the while loop

Comment: but it still skips the if statement - if (selected_ip_adr == addr_str->IpAddress.String). why won't the program execute the if statement and do the line PrintMACaddress(pAdapterInfo->Address); ? is it still not finding the MAC address?

Comment: @LisaCollins: Maybe it really isn't equal.. have you tried debugging that part?

Comment: yes i debugged it. like i said the program reaches the line if (selected_ip_adr == addr_str->IpAddress.String) and then jumps to pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next; the line inside the if statement is never executed

Comment: Then the next pAdapterInfo must be NULL

Comment: but why can't it find the mac address of the other computer? i have the ip address

Comment: @LisaCollins: Did you even read the MSDN page? "The IP_ADAPTER_INFO structure contains information about a particular network adapter on the local computer."

Comment: so i shouldn't use IP_ADAPTER_INFO? my question was how to find the MAC address of another computer

Comment: @LisaCollins: Your question was why your program was crashing, which I solved. You need to figure out how to ask a question before coming on here and wasting everyone's time by doing your own research.

Comment: no my question was 'how to find the MAC address from IP address c++'. and yes the program crashing was a problem i had but the question in the title is still the problem i'm having

Comment: No, that was your title. The crux of your question was here: "but if i try to run the client on a different computer the program crashes". Forget it. I am not wasting anymore of my time.

Comment: ok sorry if i wasn't clear enough. i have edited the title question